# html comment in head title tag - is it syntactically correct and ignored by search engines?

Tags: html, page-title

I have a web page which delivers templates to applications on external servers, so they can run in the same page environment.

Now I'd like to put html comments as placeholders in the head title tag like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><!--placeholder-->Main Site Name</title>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Is that syntactically correct and would search engines ignore the comment?

Comment: _“Is that syntactically correct”_ -> https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that syntactically correct

Yes. You can put a comment anywhere that isn't between a pair of `<` and `>`.

You could have tested this for yourself by using [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

> would search engines ignore the comment

The *should* do … but there are too many search engines to test this comprehensively and discussions about how search engines behave is off-topic.

Comment: Oops, totally forgot about the validator. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

It is syntactically correct. However, make sure to test it with a variety of browsers. At time of writing, all of the following browsers will display the comments, "<!--" and "-->" included, within the title:

- Chrome for Windows
- Firefox for Windows
- Edge
- Internet Explorer 11